# Divorce and dina d'malchuta dina

Tags: divorce, dina-dmalchusa-dina

For many centuries, in Christian lands (Italy in particular), divorce was outlawed.  But Judaism allows divorce.  Does anyone know what the Jews did in these countries, if they wanted to divorce?  If you got only a religious divorce and married again, you could be accused of bigamy.  I searched for the historical record, but could not find it.

Comment: Was divorce for non-Christians outlawed in Italy?

Comment: I know in the UK for several hundred years, the state law let the Jews do their own divorces.

Comment: @ Double AA  I'd like to know.  I know that in many cases we were allowed to rule ourselves in personal matters.  I would also like to know if polygamy was allowed for Jews when it was not for Christians.

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic for the site. It has nothing to do with Jewish Law.

Comment: Please note that for many centuries no "civil wedding" was available, but one had to go to the church (according to their own rules), and that was the official one. In Italy (based on a quick search) civil marriage is only available since 1866.

Comment: History of Jews rather than Judaism?

Comment: To those who wish to close this question- at issue here (and in Maurice Mizrahi's last several posts) is what happens when civil law contravenes Torah law but does not outlaw mitzvot. (When mitzvot are outlawed, e.g. a ban on brit milah or Torah study, we are commanded to break the law). We are not, however, commanded to slaughter or divorce, just commanded to use certain procedures if we do so. Asking about the halacha of these actions when they are forbidden by the state is absolutely on-topic.

Comment: This is 100% on-topic for this site. It's about how a rite of Judaism was practiced.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I would say that if secular marriage and divorce were not allowed, then the Jewish law would have applied. They would not have had Jews being *married* in the church (by church rules) as Jews were not part of the *sacred rites* of that religion. Thus, the state would not have done anything about it. Just as the Christians would have had the marriage records in the church, the Jews would have had the marriage (and divorce) records in the shul. I found references to the fact that the popes did not interfere with Jewish marriages even in the Papa States. However, only by implication.

Comment: @sabbahillel Yepp, I was saying quite the same. I suppose a very similar system was in practice that we can find in Israel now. Each member of a religion goes to her/his own church and their own rules apply. In my native country there was a "district rabbi" (actually a quite well paid office), who had to keep the official registers for Jews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the historical information you seek at this link:
Italy, Early Modern - Jewish Women's Archives: https://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/italy-early-modern.  It is
an encyclopedia article by Howard Tzvi Adelman. Simply put, Jews could
indeed divorce in Catholic-dominated Italy, and Adelman discusses
the conditions established by the autonomous rabbis.

In other Christian lands the situation was similar. For that information, consult in the same source 'Halachic Decisions on Family Matters in Medieval Jewish Society' by Avraham Grossman:https://jwa.org/.../halakhic-decisions-on-family-matters-in-m... He gives  ten of the most important takkanot on family matters. Two are from Babylon from the period of the Geonim, four are from Germany, two from France and two from Spain.